# How can I upgrade SSIS project dtproj files from 2008 to 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

After installing SSDT for SQL Server 2017 in VS 2017, I still cannot load an earlier version's `dtproj` file.

> This project is incompatibility with the current edition of Visual Studio

The old `.dtproj` looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ProductVersion>10.50.1600.1</ProductVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>9.0.1.0</SchemaVersion>
```

The newer dtproj looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DeploymentModel>Project</DeploymentModel>
  <ProductVersion>14.0.800.60</ProductVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>9.0.1.0</SchemaVersion>
```

In general they appear similar. I haven't really seen any documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt that addresses how to upgrade the project files.

Is there any tooling for performing upgrades?

Comment: Create a new project in 2017 and copy elements from old and paste it in to new one (if possible), or compare the code-behind and manually apply the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSDT 15.8.1 has an import .ispac wizard that will create the components for you.  Setup is a bit tricky though.

Steps to Setup

1. Install "Microsoft Analysis Services Projects" VS extension in VS2017.
2. Download SSDT 15.8.1 here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2024393
3. During install, select a "New instance" (DO NOT use existing VS2017 instance because it will fail with a vague "Recursion too deep; stack overflow" error).  New instance will be named SSDT by default.
4. Open SSDT VS instance and go File > New Project > Business Intelligence > Integration Services.
5. Select Integration Services Import Project Wizard and browse to ispac that you want to use.

All components should be created for you.

Comment: In deed, for those having "Recursion too deep; stack overflow" issue selecting a new instance will do the trick, thanks for sharing!